# Deploy WearOS app from within Android app

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, wearables

I'm currently developing an app mainly for WearOS which needs a phone companion to work. Due to the phone app needing quite powerful permissions (`BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE`, `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES`) I'll not have a good time releasing this on the PlayStore.

I want to release it open source on GitHub. This means I'll have the hassle of explaining the user how to sideload a WearOS app.

Is there a way to remotely install the WearOS app from within the phone app?

Comment: I haven't used it, but https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freepoc.wearinstaller&hl=en&gl=US

Or you could follow same approach, but it might require adb permissions, which might mean developer mode.

I don't think this approach would be pleasant or recommended, but at least users must opt into this.